# NavigationBarButton Item Not able to align vertically?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Hi I have tried to align the `navigationbar` button item position center in the navigation bar. I have changed the navigation bar height programmatically so I have able to align title its working fine, but same I have tried `leftbarbutton` and `rightbarbutton`. its has not vertically aligned center. I have tried these programmatically

**Title Alignment**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-15, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

**RightBarButton:**

```
       let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleRight), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
 //   rightButton.imageInsets =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -10;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer ,rightButton ]
```

**LeftBarButton:**

```
        let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleLeft), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -10;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer,leftButton ]
```

Please find the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Add the screenshot of your requirement please.

Comment: it *sounds* like you want to put a button in the very center of the navigation bar, in place of the title??

Comment: Add your code to show what you're doing

Comment: Yes done @PGDev

Comment: Yes@MichaelDautermann

Comment: check the code @moni15

Comment: what version of swift are you using?

Comment: swift 2.2 version